# Why $A=\{1,2\}$ is different of $B=\{\{1,2\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{\{1,2\}\}$, why aren't they equals?

I'm really confused with situations where sets are contained in itselves.

Comment: Well, for one thing, the sets do not have the same number of elements (2 vs 1).

Comment: $\{1,2\}$ is a set with two members.  $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a set with only one member.

Comment: There is no set contained in itself in your example.

Comment: @user87690 What? I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Timbuc: OP said he was confused with situations where sets are contained in themselves. I just noted that there is no such situation here.

Comment: @user87690 I see. Thank you.

Comment: But $$B\subset \mathfrak P(A)=\{\emptyset,A,\{1\},\{2\}\}$$

Comment: I have read about a set be subset of itself, so I thought that was the representation of this, but it is just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you consider a box containing two books to be the same as a box containing a box that contains two books?

These objects are clearly different and this is the issue here, $\{1,2\}$ is a set containing two elements whereas $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a set containing a set containing two elements.

Comment: Good example hehe, I was thinking in similar here to try understand, but I thought the box couldn't be considered. How wrong I was.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Two sets are equal if they have exactly the same elements. But these two have not even one element in common. $\{1,2\}$ has the two elements $'1'$ and $'2\,'$, while $\{\{1,2\}\}$ has only one element $'\{1,2\}'$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $B = \lbrace{ A \rbrace}$. So $A \in B$. $1 \notin B$ and $2 \notin B$ but $1,2 \in A$. In other words, the only element of $B$ is $A$.

Comment: How would they be represented in a Venn diagram?
Is it possible?

Comment: @Apprentice Venn diagrams are for different sets included in some bigger set, so for example if your $A, B \subset X$ then you can draw a Venn diagram; you will just have two disjoint disks.